# Multiple Conditional watermarks to be displayed in jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have 3 waterMarks, approved, canceled and Drafted, where i need it to be displayed based upon condition. So I have added Condition:

```
for cancelled copy = new Boolean(!$P{Canceledcopy_p}.toString().equals("T") ? true:false)

for approved copy = new Boolean(!$P{Approvedcopy_p}.toString().equals("T") ? true:false)

for drafted copy = new Boolean(!$P{FinalApprover_P}.toString().equals("T") ? true:false)
```

it displays fine when i preview, but when i generate the report it does not display.Below is my java code:

```
     if (POApplst.getStatusID() == 1) {
        map.put("Approvedcopy_p", "F");
        map.put("FinalApprover_P", "T");
        } else {
        if (POApplst.get(POApplst.size() - 1).getStatusID() != 1) {
            map.put("Approvedcopy_p", "T");
            map.put("FinalApprover_P", "F");
        } else {             
            map.put("Approvedcopy_p", "F");
            map.put("FinalApprover_P", "T");
                if (Canceled) {                                   
                    map.put("Canceledcopy_p", "F");
                    map.put("Approvedcopy_p", "T");
                    map.put("FinalApprover_P", "T");
                } else {
                    map.put("Canceledcopy_p", "T");
                }
        }
    }
          if (Canceled) {
            map.put("Canceledcopy_p", "F");
            map.put("Approvedcopy_P", "T");
            map.put("FinalApprover_P", "T");
        } else {
            map.put("Canceledcopy_p", "T");
        }
```

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: There is no error in console. i added images from palette and then set Image Expression: $P{FinalApprover_P}, $P{Approvedcopy_P}, $P{Canceledcopy_p}, Next PrintWhenExpression as for Canceled     new Boolean(!$P{Canceledcopy_p}.toString().equals("T") ? true:false)

for approved copy                                                                               new Boolean(!$P{Approvedcopy_p}.toString().equals("T") ? true:false)

for drafted copy                                                                                   new Boolean(!$P{FinalApprover_P}.toString().equals("T") ? true:false)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Boolean type(T or F). what i made is, if it is approved then others will be null except approved copy where approved image will be loaded from bufferedImage approved = ImageIO.read(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/image path/" + "logo.jpg"));. in similar way, all will be null except what copy it is.

```
     if (POApplst.get(POApplst.size() - 1).getStatusID() != 1) {
                    parameter.put("Approvedcopy_p", null);
                    parameter.put("FinalApprover_P", draft);

                } else {

                    parameter.put("Approvedcopy_p", approved);
                    parameter.put("FinalApprover_P", null);

                    if (Canceled) {
                        parameter.put("Canceledcopy_p", canceled);
                        parameter.put("Approvedcopy_p", null);
                        parameter.put("FinalApprover_P", null);
                    } else {
                        parameter.put("Canceledcopy_p", null);
                    }
                }
```